# Using metaclass to automatically assign member variables of a class

Tags: python, metaclass

In a Python class, I would like to automatically assign member variables to be the same as the `__init__` function arguments, like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2 = 1):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
```

- I would like to explicitly have argument names in the **init**
  function for the sake of code clarity.
- I don't want to use decorators for the same reason.

Is it possible to achieve this using a custom metaclass?

Comment: honestly if you just want to assign attributes directly passed to `__init__` then you could just use a `collections.namedtuple`.

Comment: Why would you like to do this ? Depending on the concrete use case there might be quite a few different (and more or less appropriate) solutions.

Comment: I have a long list of argument for my classes (say around 10) and I don't want to explicitly type them one by one. Later in the class I used these argument for further calculations.

Comment: @motam79 do you realize that any solution involving a custom metaclass, inspection etc will require more code - and a code that's much more complex to write and maintain - than those ten straight assignments ?

Comment: A small voice of Alan J. Perlis inside me wants to say that if you need to pass 10 arguments to a class, you probably missed some. :P

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, this is a recurring pattern in my code. If I have 20 classes each having 10 variables to initialize, the lines quickly add up. I was thinking to use Json  to initialize classes, but I loose the benefit of code completion in PyCharm.

Comment: @motam79 if it's recurring pattern then indeed it might be worth doing some automation.

Answer (score 1):

First, a disclaimer. Python object creation and initialization can be complicated and highly dynamic. This means that it can be difficult to come up with a solution that works for the corner cases. Moreover, the solutions tend to use some darker magic, and so when they inevitably *do* go wrong they can be hard to debug.

Second, the fact that your class has so many initialization parameters might be a hint that it has *too* many parameters. Some of them are probably related and can fit together in a smaller class. For example, if I'm building a car, it's better to have:

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, tires, engine):
        self.tires = tires
        self.engine = engine

class Tire:

    def __init__(self, radius, winter=False):
        self.radius = radius
        self.winter = winter

class Engine:

    def __init__(self, big=True, loud=True):
        self.big = big
        self.loud = loud
```

as opposed to

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, tire_radius, winter_tires=False, 
                 engine_big=True, engine_loud=True):
        self.tire_radius = tire_radius
        self.winter_tires winter_tires
        self.engine_big = engine_big
        self.engine_loud = engine_loud
```

All of that said, here is a solution. I haven't used this in my own code, so it isn't "battle-tested". But it at least appears to work in the simple case. Use at your own risk.

First, metaclasses aren't necessary here, and we can use a simple decorator on the `__init__` method. I think this is more readable, anyways, since it is clear that we are only modifying the behavior of `__init__`, and not something deeper about class creation.

```
import inspect
import functools

def unpack(__init__):
    sig = inspect.signature(__init__)

    @functools.wraps(__init__)
    def __init_wrapped__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bound = sig.bind(self, *args, **kwargs)
        bound.apply_defaults()

        # first entry is the instance, should not be set
        # discard it, taking only the rest
        attrs = list(bound.arguments.items())[1:]

        for attr, value in attrs:
            setattr(self, attr, value)

        return __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return __init_wrapped__
```

This decorator uses the `inspect` module to retrieve the signature of the `__init__` method. Then we simply loop through the attributes and use `setattr` to assign them.

In use, it looks like:

```
class Foo(object):

    @unpack
    def __init__(self, a, b=88):
        print('This still runs!')
```

so that

```
>>> foo = Foo(42)
This still runs!
>>> foo.a
42
>>> foo.b
88
```

I am not certain that every introspection tool will see the right signature of the decorated `__init__`. In particular, I'm not sure if Sphinx will do the "right thing". But at least the `inspect` module's `signature` function will return the signature of the wrapped function, as can be tested.

If you *really* want a metaclass solution, it's simple enough (but less readable and more magic, IMO). You need only write a class factory that applies the `unpack` decorator:

```
def unpackmeta(clsname, bases, dct):
    dct['__init__'] = unpack(dct['__init__'])
    return type(clsname, bases, dct)

class Foo(metaclass=unpackmeta):

    def __init__(self, a, b=88):
        print('This still runs!')
```

The output will be the same as the above example.

Comment: Thanks, Is there an equivalent to "inspect.signature" in python 2.7?

Comment: Yes, `getargspec`, but it isn't a drop-in equivalent. You'll have to do some fiddling around. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader.